# Subset of $V$ with countably infinite basis

Tags: vector-spaces, proof-verification

I came across the following exercise:

> Let $V$ be the vector space which is spanned by a countably infinite set.  Prove every linearly independent subset of $V$ is finite or countably infinite.

Is this statement even true?  A counterexample might be $V$ as the span of infinite real sequences with $1$ in the $i^{th}$ slot and $0$ elsewhere.  This space is spanned by a countably infinite set, but $\hbox{Span}\{(1,0,0,\ldots),(0,1,0,\ldots)\}$ is *uncountably* infinite since it admits real multiples of either of the basis vectors.

If the exercise is wrong, is there a similar *true* statement that the author might have intended?  Perhaps that the linearly independent subsets are "spanned by finite or countably infinite sets"?

Comment: The so called counterexample does not satisfy the condition - it is not a *linearly independent* subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is correct.

Let $A$ be the countable generating set, and let $U$ be an uncountable linearly independent set. It can be extended to a basis $B$ of the whole space. Now consider the subset $C$ of elements of $B$ that appear in the $B$-decompositions of elements of $A$. Since only finitely many elements are involved in the decomposition of each element of $A$, the set $C$ is countable. But $C$ also clearly generates the vector space $V$. This contradicts the fact that it is a proper subset of the basis $B$ (since $B$ is uncountable).

In your example, the given span isn't a linearly independent set.

Comment: +1. Nice approach. But in this AC is used. But for this particular result, I don't think it's required.